# Interweaving numpy arrays stored in the same object

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a Pandas Series that looks likes this:

```
ID           metric_name          variant_name
ID-1         ordertype1           variant         ([0.01, 0.02, 0....
             ordertype1           variant         ([0.01, 0.02, 0....

dtype: object
```

When you look at them individually, you get the following:

For `result.loc[('ID-1, 'odertype1', 'variant')]`:

```
(array([0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04]),
 array([0.05,0.06, 0.07, 0.08]))
```

For `result.loc[('ID-1, 'odertype2', 'variant')]`:

```
(array([0.09, 0.10, 0.11, 0.12]),
 array([0.13,0.14, 0.15, 0.16]))
```

How can I extract the values from these arrays so that they interweave for both the first and second of each arrays, then store this info the column of a dataframe?

I.e. I want:

```
Column1  Column2
0.01     0.05
0.09     0.13
0.02     0.06
0.1      0.14
0.03     0.07
0.11     0.15
0.04     0.08
0.12     0.16
```

Comment: Do you need the index names? or just interested in the data?

Comment: These kinds of situations are a great example of how the flexibility granted by the `object` dtype is both a blessing and a curse. Often when I store things like experiment outputs in a Pandas data frame like this, I usually regret it and wish that  had stored them in files or a SQLite database instead. You can't even save this table to disk without pickling it! Shoving everything into a DF is really convenient for quick and dirty scripts, but then you end up having to fix it later.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a list of all the indices you want to select from your series:

```
req_indices = [('ID-1', 'odertype1', 'variant'), ('ID-1', 'odertype2', 'variant')]
```

You can index into your series using this list, and pass the result to `np.vstack` to create a 2D array:

```
tmp = np.vstack(result.loc[req_indices])
```

which gives:

```
array([[0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04],
       [0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08],
       [0.09, 0.1 , 0.11, 0.12],
       [0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16]])
```

Then, reshape the transpose of this array to 2 columns:

```
res = tmp.T.reshape((-1, 2))
```

and you have your desired array:

```
array([[0.01, 0.05],
       [0.09, 0.13],
       [0.02, 0.06],
       [0.1 , 0.14],
       [0.03, 0.07],
       [0.11, 0.15],
       [0.04, 0.08],
       [0.12, 0.16]])
```

You can convert this to a dataframe by specifying the column names:

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=["Col1", "Col2"])
```

Comment: Ideally you'd copy the index from the original `Series` over to the new `DataFrame`. Also I don't know how well this will generalize to an arbitrary-sized input. You probably need to collect all the arrays in a list, rather than just `arr1` and `arr2`.

Comment: @shadowtalker I didn't think OP cared about the indices because they haven't shown it in their desired dataframe. Generalizing to more than two inputs is actually easier than what I had before, I have edited my answer for that

Answer (score 1):

One very general approach is to first convert each pair of arrays into a Pandas data frame, and then `pd.concat` all those data frames together.

First, let's reconstruct the data in a Pandas `Series`, which is what it looks like you are asking about:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Construct the data
results = pd.DataFrame([
    {
        "ID": "ID-1",
        "metric_name": "ordertype1",
        "variant_name": "variant",
        "result": (
            np.array([0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04]),
            np.array([0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08]),
        ),
    },
    {
        "ID": "ID-1",
        "metric_name": "ordertype2",
        "variant_name": "variant",
        "result": (
            np.array([0.09, 0.10, 0.11, 0.12]),
            np.array([0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16]),
        ),
    },
]).set_index(["ID", "metric_name", "variant_name"])["result"]
```

It looks like this when `print()`-ed:

```
ID    metric_name  variant_name
ID-1  ordertype1   variant         ([0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04], [0.05, 0.06, 0.07, ...
      ordertype2   variant         ([0.09, 0.1, 0.11, 0.12], [0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0...
Name: result, dtype: object
```

We can write a helper function to convert this pair of arrays into a data frame, and apply it to each element of `results`:

```py
def result_to_frame(result_arrs):
    return pd.DataFrame(
        np.column_stack(result_arrs),
        columns=["Column1", "Column2"],
    ).rename_axis(index="i")

results_frames = results.map(result_to_frame)
```

Now, `results_frames.iat[0]` will look like this:

```
   Column1  Column2
i
0     0.01     0.05
1     0.02     0.06
2     0.03     0.07
3     0.04     0.08
```

Finally, we `concat` everything together, converting the `Series` to a dict in order to expose its index values to `pd.concat`, which will use them as the outer index levels of the result:

```py
results_flat = pd.concat(
    results_frames.to_dict(),
    names=results_frames.index.names,
)
```

```
                           Column1  Column2
                        i
ID-1 ordertype1 variant 0     0.01     0.05
                        1     0.02     0.06
                        2     0.03     0.07
                        3     0.04     0.08
     ordertype2 variant 0     0.09     0.13
                        1     0.10     0.14
                        2     0.11     0.15
                        3     0.12     0.16
```

It might be faster to pre-allocate the desired output array or data frame and copy data into it, as in `pho`'s answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/77840808/2954547). However you'll have to do some manual bookkeeping in order to preserve the indexes with that technique, whereas my solution above handles arbitrary indexes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

directly use `numpy`:

```
res = np.array(list(results)).transpose(2,0,1).reshape(-1,2)
res
array([[0.01, 0.05],
       [0.09, 0.13],
       [0.02, 0.06],
       [0.1 , 0.14],
       [0.03, 0.07],
       [0.11, 0.15],
       [0.04, 0.08],
       [0.12, 0.16]])
```

You could then transform into dataframe:

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=["Col1", "Col2"])
```